# Arcane Archer "within range"

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, arcane-archer

I was reading the arcane archer class because of another post, and while reading the abilities it kept referring to using them "within range".
How do they define within range? Clearly the weapon focus feat longbow or shortbow should get us close to the answer. But does it mean with no range penalties for that bow, or one range penalties,...?
Ideally I would like to know for pathfinder but I expect the same question exists for 3.x as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All ranged weapons have a maximum range; beyond this, targets are out of range, and within, they are in range. That is what the arcane archer is referring to. And yes, it is the same in 3.5 and Pathfinder.

<sub>[Gamemastering > Combat > Ranged Attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#ranged-attacks) (PF), [Combat > Actions in Combat > Ranged Attacks](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#rangedAttacks) (D&D 3.5)</sub>

> The maximum range for a thrown weapon is five range increments. For projectile weapons, it is 10 range increments. Some ranged weapons have shorter maximum ranges, as specified in their descriptions.

Comment: So the penalty ranges would still be included. I was most curious about this because of the seeker arrow ability. The greater ranges makes it far more effective. Thank you